# simulating 2 variables with correlation with a lognormal distribution R

Tags: r

Trying to simulate 2 variables that are correlated, with a lognormal distribution for both.  Is this possible in R?  I can do it in a normal distribution like this

```
library(faux)
test <- rnorm_multi(10000, 
            m = c(275, 2), 
            sd = c(65, 1),
            r = .5,
            empirical = F)
```

where means are 275 and 2; sd's are 65 and 1; with a .5 correlation coefficient

I have found the function rlnorm.rplus in `library(compositions)` which does lognormal distributions, but don't see how to input standard deviations, and having issues converting cor coefficient into covariance matrix

Greatly appreciate any help here!

Comment: Simulate a bivariate normal distribution and exponentiate the two components?

Answer (score 1):

See [this Cross Validated Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132855/expectation-variance-and-correlation-of-a-bivariate-lognormal-distribution).

Say you want a bivariate log-normal distribution with means = `c(275, 2)`, standard deviations = `c(65, 1)`, and correlation coefficient = `0.5`:

```
m <- c(275, 2)
s <- c(65, 1)
r <- 0.5
```

First get the parameters of the log-normal distribution (the mean and standard deviation of the corresponding normal distribution) and the anti-diagonal of the covariance matrix:

```
sigma <- sqrt(log(s^2/m^2 + 1))
mu <- log(m) - sigma^2/2
rho <- log(r*prod(s)/prod(m) + 1)
```

We can now simulate from the specified bivariate log-normal:

```
y <- exp(mvtnorm::rmvnorm(1e6, mu, diag(sigma^2 - rho) + rho))
```

Sanity check:

```
colMeans(y)
#> [1] 275.04160   1.99803
apply(y, 2, sd)
#> [1] 65.0113814  0.9965434
cor(y)[2]
#> [1] 0.4986894
```