# Sampling two correlated random variables using the gamma distribution

Tags: r, statistics, gamma-distribution

I have two random variables that are distributed by the gamma distribution. These random variables are negatively correlated by a coefficient of -.1. I'm not sure how to incorporate the correlation correctly. By looking at many different examples, I've boiled it down to the following code, but I don't think this is correct for my purposes because it only changes one of the RVs and leaves the other exactly the same.

```
# Number of observations
n <- 10

# Parameters for the gamma distribution
shape1 <- 2
shape2 <- 3

# Generate two independent gamma-distributed random variables
X <- rgamma(n, shape = shape1)
Y <- rgamma(n, shape = shape2)

# Correlation coefficient
corrcoef <- -.1

# Create a correlation matrix
corr_matrix <- matrix(c(1, corrcoef, corrcoef, 1), nrow = 2)

# Cholesky decomposition to get the lower triangular matrix
cholesky_matrix <- chol(corr_matrix)

# Create a matrix of uncorrelated variables
uncorrelated_matrix <- cbind(X, Y)

# Transform the uncorrelated variables to have the desired correlation
correlated_matrix <- uncorrelated_matrix %*% cholesky_matrix

# Extract the correlated variables
correlated_X <- correlated_matrix[, 1]
correlated_Y <- correlated_matrix[, 2]

# Compare summarry of X, Y, correlated_X, and correlated_Y
summary(X)
summary(Y)
summary(correlated_X)
summary(correlated_Y)
```

I understand that this gets me what I "want", in that it reshapes `Y` such that it's follows a gamma distribution *and* it's negatively correlated to `X` as specified. But **I don't want to leave `X` static and only change `Y`**. Ideally both `correlated_X` and `correlated_Y` would change and have the same mean as `X` and `Y`.

I guess what I'm looking for is for the samples to be transformed such that the sum of squares is minimized: `(mean(correlated_X) - mean(X))^2 + (mean(correlated_Y) - mean(Y))^2`

Is there another process that would change both random variables "equally" instead of leaving one static and changing the other?

Comment: Why not make a separate "correlated matrix" where the roles of X and Y are swapped and then that the means of both matrices? I have no idea whether that would satisfy your sum of squares criterion, but that criterion doesn't really look to be something that would be consistent with the goal of having the correlation coefficient remaining fixed.

Comment: @IRTFM thanks for your reply. Do you have an example of what you mean, or could you maybe point me in the right direction. I don't really even need it to satisfy that sum of squares criterion. I just know that my two gamma distributed RVs are negatively correlated, and I want to slightly adjust them both to introduce that negative correlation. Does not need to be perfect, but I'm not really sure where to begin. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

A general procedure to sample from any bivariate distribution for which you have the quantile functions of the marginal distributions and the desired correlation coefficient (`rho`):

1. Initialize `r = rho`.
2. Generate a bivariate Gaussian copula with a correlation coefficient equal to `r`.
3. Use inverse transform sampling to convert the copula to one with the desired marginal distributions.
4. Calculate the correlation coefficient of the bivariate distribution resulting from Step 3.
5. Update `r` according to a stochastic root finding scheme. Check if `r` has converged. If it has, return `r`. If it has not, return to Step 2.

---

For Step 2, we can use a [bivariate log-normal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150452/9463489) copula, since the log-normal distribution has the same support as your bivariate gamma distribution. Additionally, we can match moments.

I'll demonstrate the first four steps using a very large sample size so that the correlation coefficient of the sample is close to the actual correlation coefficient.

```
library(mvtnorm)

set.seed(976317713)
n <- 1e7 # number of samples
# parameters of the gamma marginal distributions
shape1 <- 2
shape2 <- 3
rate1 <- 1
rate2 <- 1
rho <- -0.1 # desired correlation coefficient

shapes <- c(shape1, shape2)
rates <- c(rate1, rate2)
m <- shapes/rates # means of the gamma marginal distributions
s <- sqrt(m/rates) # standard deviations of the gamma marginal distributions
# parameters of the moment-matched log-normal marginal distributions
sigma <- sqrt(log(s^2/m^2 + 1))
mu <- log(m) - sigma^2/2
d <- log(rho*prod(s)/prod(m) + 1) # covariance anti-diagonal
# Step 2: bivariate normal whose corresponding log-normal has the desired
# correlation coefficient
y <- rmvnorm(n, mu, diag(sigma^2 - d) + d)
# check the correlation coefficient
cor(exp(y[,1]), exp(y[,2]))
#> [1] -0.1001247
# Step 2: bivariate Gaussian copula
u <- pnorm(y, rep(mu, each = n), rep(sigma, each = n))
# Step 3: inverse transform sampling
x <- qgamma(u, rep(shapes, each = n), rep(rates, each = n))
# check that the resulting marginal distributions are the desired gammas
ks.test(x[,1], pgamma, shape1, rate1)
#> 
#>  Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#> 
#> data:  x[, 1]
#> D = 0.00021873, p-value = 0.725
#> alternative hypothesis: two-sided
ks.test(x[,2], pgamma, shape2, rate2)
#> 
#>  Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#> 
#> data:  x[, 2]
#> D = 0.00025568, p-value = 0.5303
#> alternative hypothesis: two-sided
# Step 4: Correlation coefficient of `x`
cor(x[,1], x[,2])
#> [1] -0.1104764
```

The correlation coefficient is a bit off the target of -0.1. Using stochastic root-finding, we can adjust `rho` in order to get much closer to the desired correlation coefficient. The following function performs the entire process.

```
rgammaCopula <- function(n, shape1, shape2, rate1, rate2, rho, k = 1e3, reps = 1e3) {
  shapes <- c(shape1, shape2)
  rates <- c(rate1, rate2)
  m <- shapes/rates
  s <- sqrt(m/rates)
  sigmasq <- log(s^2/m^2 + 1)
  sigma <- sqrt(sigmasq)
  mu <- log(m) - sigmasq/2
  mus <- rep(mu, each = k)
  sigmas <- rep(sigma, each = k)
  shapes <- rep(shapes, each = k)
  rates <- rep(rates, each = k)
  sm <- prod(s/m)
  num <- den <- 0
  r <- rho
  # stochastic root finding
  for (i in seq_len(reps)) {
    d <- log(r*sm + 1)
    x <- matrix(
      qgamma(
        pnorm(rmvnorm(k, mu, diag(sigmasq - d) + d), mus, sigmas),
        shapes,
        rates
      ), k, 2
    )
    
    num <- num + r^2
    den <- den + r*cor(x[,1], x[,2])
    r <- rho*num/den
  }
  
  d <- log(r*sm + 1)
  list(
    x = matrix(
      qgamma(
        pnorm(
          rmvnorm(n, mu, diag(sigmasq - d) + d),
          rep(mu, each = n),
          rep(sigma, each = n)
        ),
        rep(c(shape1, shape2), each = n),
        rep(c(rate1, rate2), each = n)
      ), n, 2
    ),
    r = r
  )
}
```

Testing:

```
n <- 10
res <- rgammaCopula(n, shape1, shape2, rate1, rate2, rho)
colMeans(res$x)
#> [1] 1.988554 2.875326
apply(res$x, 2, var)
#> [1] 2.803401 2.270023
cor(res$x[,1], res$x[,2])
#> [1] 0.1274439
```

With only 10 samples the mean, variance, and correlation coefficient statistics are highly variable. Use `res$r` to generate 10 million samples and check the statistics again:

```
res <- rgammaCopula(1e7, shape1, shape2, rate1, rate2, res$r, 0, 0)
colMeans(res$x)
#> [1] 2.000603 3.000251
apply(res$x, 2, var)
#> [1] 2.000278 3.000842
cor(res$x[,1], res$x[,2])
#> [1] -0.1003074
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this , which I thought was clear in the comment:

```
uncorrelated_matrix <- cbind(X, Y)

# Transform the uncorrelated variables to have the desired correlation
correlated_matrix2 <- uncorrelated_matrix[, 2:1] %*%   #reverse X and Y
                                 cholesky_matrix
corr_both <- (correlated_matrix + correlated_matrix2)/2
```

I checked to make sure that the sum of two gammas was again gamma, so the mean of the two gamma matrices should be two gamma columns.